# How to add ID into jquery plugin selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that was written by a previous team member and for some reason it only allows for #ids to be used in it, not classes.

```
 $("#content-builder-1,#content-builder-2").templateEditor({
   // options.
 });
```

My issue is, I am using an external button to add items to a page. and what I can see is `$("#content-builder")` when we want to add in additional items, we need to add it in with `$("#content-builder-1, #content-builder-2")`

as I am dynamically adding additional divs with incremental IDs to the page, I am wondering how would I add this so the function automatically adds it.

I've thought about using `.on()` or `.live()` but I am unsure as to how to add in the additional ID's into the main loader.

`$("#content-builder-1, #content-builder-2, #content-builder-3")` and so on.

Is there a best method to add this?

Comment: assign a common class to them and use $(".classname")

Comment: `as I am dynamically adding additional divs with incremental IDs to the page,` Provide us with this code and we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must stick to the current approach, i.e. target different elements by their IDs, you could use an "id attribute starts with" selector like this:

```
$("[id^=content-builder-]").templateEditor({
  // options.
});
```

However, the plugin cannot possibly know what type of selector generated the jQuery selection it gets to work with, so if it's correct that it only works "with ids", it has to be because it internally relies on each element to have an ID, not beacuse it requires the elements to have been selected by their IDs originally.

Therefore, my guess is that giving each of those elements a common class and selecting by that should work, in which case your code (as others have mentioned) would look like this:

```
$(".content-builder").templateEditor({
  // options.
});
```

But as mentioned, it's possible that each element still has to have an ID for the plugin to work.

`.on()` is not relevant in this case as there is/seems to be no event listening going on and therefore nothing you can delegate to a common parent.

Answer (score 1):

add same class to all elements like that:

```
$('.classname').templateEditor({
   // options.
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, class name would work. A cleaner option, IMHO, would be to use a data attribute.

So, you would end up with something like:

```
    <div id="foo" data-role="content-builder">Hello world!</div>
    <div id="bar" data-role="content-builder">Hello world!</div>
```

And your selector would be something like:

```
$('[data-role="content-builder"]').on('click', function() {    
      alert($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

Edit: Another option would be, if you wanted to add some kind of incremented id, you could use an attribute like this:

```
     <div data-content-builder="27" id="yup">Adios</div>
     <div data-content-builder="28" id="Nope">So long</div>
```

Then you could select them by that attribute, a la:

```
$("[data-content-builder]").on('click', function() { 
    alert($(this).data('content-builder'));
});
```

Here's an example (updated with both): http://jsfiddle.net/xj491uju/

(Obviously, you'd be doing something other than click — in your case, templateeditor — but you get the point.)